# Laravel session table add additional column

Tags: session, laravel, laravel-4, logout

I want to add an extra column `user_id` on `session` table.

The reason is, some time there are spammer to sign up fake account, once I know that the user is spammer, I want to log the user out by deleting the session record.

Is it possible to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the session migration schema:

```
Schema::create('sessions', function($table)
{
    $table->string('id')->unique();
    $table->text('payload');
    $table->integer('last_activity');
    $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned(); //// ADD IT!
});
```

You can add whatever column you like on it, Laravel won't mind.

Or you can create a new migration and make it add a column on that table.

```
$table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
```

You can create a Model for it:

```
class SessionModel extends Eloquent {

}
```

And do whatever you need with it:

```
$session = SessionModel::find(Session::getId());
$session->user_id = 1;
$session->save();
```

But if you're thinking about adding more info to the payload, which is where Laravel keeps the session data, although I think it's possible, you'll have to dig a bit more in Laravel's code to do that.

Comment: @Antonio Carlos Ribeiro thank you. I was at same condition. I had query, can you let me know, that I am planning to lock login from single location at a time and so I am moving ahead with database Auth/session drivers. So login with same credential from another location show a message "Already loggied in from some another location". Would this approach be fine? Thanks

Comment: I get this error when ever I try to save session`SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'updated_at' in 'field list' `

Comment: @EdmundSulzanok if you create a Model class for the session, you need to make sure you include `public $timestamps = false;`. Otherwise, your schema needs to include `$table->timestamps();`.

Answer (score 1):

Short version of migration

```
if( Schema::hasTable('sessions') ) {
    $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
}
```

Need to check if exist `session` table. Or create it before:

```
php artisan session:table
php artisan migrate
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/session#introduction

Answer (score 1):

This is the session migration schema:

```
Schema::create('sessions', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string('id')->unique();
        $table->integer('user_id')->nullable();
        $table->string('ip_address', 45)->nullable();
        $table->text('user_agent')->nullable();
        $table->text('device')->nullable();
        $table->text('payload');
        $table->integer('last_activity');
    });
```

To add the information to the payload after adding COLUMN to the TABLE, just change the DatabaseSessionHandler class.

path: vendor/laravel/framework/src/illuminate/Session

Ex:

1º Creates the function

```
protected function device()
{
    $agent = new \Jenssegers\Agent\Agent;

    if ($agent->isDesktop()){
        $device = 'desktop';
    }

    return $device;
}
```

2º add in function addRequestInformation (& $ payload)

```
protected function addRequestInformation(&$payload)
{
    if ($this->container->bound('request')) {
        $payload = array_merge($payload, [
            'ip_address' => $this->ipAddress(),
            'user_agent' => $this->userAgent(),
            'device' => $this->device(),
        ]);
    }

    return $this;
}
```

Ready, device added to the table when the user login.