# How to get the session ID stored in database?

Tags: php, session, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to add extra info in the sessions table by making another model `Sessions`. I am using the approach detailed in the following question's answer;

[Laravel session table add additional column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20541251/laravel-session-table-add-additional-column)

#### Table

Fields:

- id - varchar(50) - laravel stores a 40 character string here
- payload - mediumtext - typically string of 265 characters
- last_activity - int(11)
- user_id - bigint(20)
- type - varchar(15) - default('biz')
- created_at - timestamp - default(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)

#### Model

```
class Sessions extends BaseModel
{
    protected $table = 'sessions';
    protected $fillable = array(
        'id', 
        'payload', 
        'last_activity', 
        'user_id', 
        'type', 
        'created_at');

    public static function getCurrent()
    {
        return Sessions::find(Session::getId());
    }
}
```

#### Controller

```
public function postLogin()
{
    if (\Auth::biz()->attempt(\Input::only(array('email', 'password')), 
        \Input::get('persist', 'no') == 'yes')) {
        $session = Sessions::getCurrent(); // returns NULL
        // fields getting values
        $session->save();
        return \Redirect::route('marketer.home');
    } else {
        return \Redirect::back()->withInput()->with('loginFail', true);
    }
}
```

I am using laravel v4.2.16 with database based session management. The function `Session::getId()` doesn't return the id stored in the database thus I can't get the current session's modal through my `Sessions::getCurrent()` method.

The approach worked before thus we had built many optimized queries on it.

Comment: The table exists in the database, right?
What does Session::getId() return? Null?

Comment: @VitoNordloh yes the table exists. I have tried running it with dd(Session::getId()) and it returns a similarly encoded string which doesn't match with anything under id column.

Comment: @UmairAhmed, within the same session? or are you re-login?

Comment: @LeaTano No, its the same session.

Comment: @UmairAhmed the session_id is totally different or shorter? if it is shorter, make sure the session column length is big enough. If the session_id is completly different please, share with  the completed code with us... I can help you with it.

Comment: @UmairAhmed, please also, include the session table structure

Comment: @LeaTano it is completely different, but same length.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$user = \Auth::user(); in the view file
```

and then print $user variable as:

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($user);
echo "</pre>";
exit;
```

See, if that helps.

Comment: No, I don't need the user here. I want to get the current session's row from database.

Comment: Strange, just after logging in user, I put 
dd(Session::has(\Auth::biz()->id()));
which returns false while \Auth::biz()->check() returns true...

Comment: In your Auth Redirect part change to: return \Redirect::route('marketer.home')->with(array('key' => 'value')); and Then echo Session::has('key');

Comment: Try this: print_r(Session::has(\Auth::biz()->toArray()));

Comment: the first returns as false, 
the second, returns 'Call to a member function toArray() on a non-object'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68481/discussion-between-gaurav-dave-and-umair-ahmed).

Answer (score 0):

You need to call static `Session::unguard();` get the id and then `Session::reguard();`